# Is there a common definition for locomotives, wagons and other types of rail transport units?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I'm looking for a concise<sup>1</sup> way of describing "any railway unit". It can be locomotives, railway cars, platform cars, specialized railway machines -- basically anything on a railroad.

At this moment I have several ideas, for example:

- railway veichle;
- railway unit;
- unit of railroad transportation.

Not sure which to pick and if there a specialized term I should use.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>: I'm making an accent on conciseness because I'm a programmer by trade and of course in dire need for a variable name. Right now I'm contemplating something along the lines of RailwayUnitNumber.</sub>

Comment: Maybe consider this? (Database of UK 'rolling stock numbers') https://www.ltsv.com/rd/numberseries_list.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common term is "**[rolling stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_stock)**" in general, and "rolling stock unit" for an individual unit. This refers to all railway vehicles, and is common jargon in the industry.

Comment: This link is wonderful, but I have a question. It looks like "rolling stock" is a set of objects (comment by @Michael Harvey, [wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20070306033115/http://www.askoxford.com/concise_oed/rollingstock?view=uk) [sources](https://web.archive.org/web/20090222122020/http://www.bartleby.com/61/0/R0290000.html)).  
Can the term be used for describing a singular unit of rolling stock? For context I'd like to get a term for `blank` in "The identifier number of this `blank` is 123", where I'm actually talking about a railcar, or a passenger car, maybe a locomotive etc.

Comment: @HeavyJS I searched for "one rolling stock" to see if I could find the term used for a single unit, and found [just one instance](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/International_GAAP_2018/GxdEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22one+rolling+stock%22&pg=PA1677&printsec=frontcover). I found [many hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rolling%20stock%20unit%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2004,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) for "rolling stock unit".

Comment: @swmcdonnell Did you open the link and read the first sentence? It says, "*The term **rolling stock** in the rail transport industry refers to railway vehicles, including both powered and unpowered vehicles*". That's the complete definition. The link in your answer is more accurately "a list of Wikipedia pages about railway vehicles", rather than a list of subtypes of railway vehicles, so of course it includes the page about the umbrella term.